# How can I prove that W is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is if $v_0 \in \Bbb{R}^n$ is a fixed vector and we define $W\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ to be the set of all vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ that are othogonal to the particular vector $v_0$. Then using the subspace test, and abstract properties of dot products how does one prove that $W$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1):

The bilinearity of the dot product gaurantees $\psi:v\mapsto v\cdot v_0$ defines a linear map on $\Bbb R^n$ and therefore $\ker(\psi)$ is an $\Bbb R^n$ subspace where $\ker(\psi)=\{v\in\Bbb R^n:v\cdot v_0=0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The subspace test requires showing that $W$ (all vectors orthogonal to $v_0$, i.e. all vectors $w$ such that $w\cdot v_0=0$) is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Take two arbitrary vectors in $W$, call them $w_1$ and $w_2$. All we start with is that $w_1\cdot v_0= 0$  and $w_2\cdot v_0= 0$. To show closure under addition we need that $(w_1+w_2)\in W$, which means we need to show that $(w_1+w_2)\cdot v_0 =0$. Which property of dot product give us this? Similarly we need to show that for an arbitrary vector $w\in W$ that $cw\in W$ for any scalar $c$.

Comment: The property for the dot product would be the distributive property correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that $W$ is not empty which it is indeed because $0\in W$; that it is stable by addition and multiplication by a scalar.

Two vectors $w_1,w_2\in W$, are such that $w_1\cdot v_0= w_2\cdot v_0=0$. So $(w_1+w_2)\cdot v_0=\lambda w_1\cdot v_0=0$

And we’re done.